# VB.net variable step increase

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

I'm trying to step a for loop with changing step sizes:

```
Dim i As Integer = 1
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer

For s As Integer = 0 To T Step i
    b = 999
    a = 0
    For t As Integer = s To T
        do stuff with a
        Select Case a
            Case <= b
                b = a
            Case > b
                i = t + 1
                Exit For
        End Select
    Next t
Next s
```

I want the "s" loop to step forward depending on how far the "t" loop has gone and therefore I give it the value "t+1" before exiting the "t" loop...

Am I missing something?
thx a lot!

Comment: what is the initial value of T? Pretty sure in VB.NET T and t will be considered the same variable and you won't be able to re-use t in the second For loop - it won't compile.

Comment: You should ask a question related to *what* you want to do rather than *how* you think something should be done

Comment: You can't have two variable named t and T. Does it even compile? Also, you'll need to increase "s" manually instead of using a "Step i" since vb.net cache the To and the Step. An other option is to use a while loop. Lastly... use meaningful variable names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't alter the value of `step` once the loop has started. The MSDN documentation on For loops says this:

> When a For...Next loop starts, Visual Basic evaluates start, end, and step. Visual Basic evaluates these values only at this time and then assigns start to counter. Before the statement block runs, Visual Basic compares counter to end. If counter is already larger than the end value (or smaller if step is negative), the For loop ends and control passes to the statement that follows the Next statement. Otherwise, the statement block runs.

and

> Changing the value of start, end, or step doesn't affect the iteration values that were determined when the loop was first entered.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx for more details.

An alternative to increasing the step could be to use `Continue For`, at a point where an appropriate condition exists, to stop execution of the current loop iteration and move straight to the next one. Or, you might be able to re-implement the functionality using `While` loops to give you a bit more flexibility.

Aside from this, your sample code won't compile because you a) you haven't declared `t`/`T`and b) you can't use `t` a second time as the counter for the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help!
The capital `T` was just for the minimum example ;-) In my full code it is called `perioden`
I finally used a `Do ... Loop`with some `Exit Do`conditions... works fine!

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad you found a solution, but please don't post comments as answers. Once you have enough reputation (50 I think) you'll be able to add comments to other answers. You might find that this "answer" is removed by the moderators at some point, they don't like answers that don't answer the question. That's just my friendly hint :-)